Set default request as TURBO_STREAM in rails 7
I have a newly created Rails 7 application, in that application, I am using form_with, link_to, and button_to and all these tags are sending the request as HTML, I want it to be processed as a TURBO_STREAM request by default.

got any errors in your browser console? type Turbo in your browser console to check if it's loaded. form_with and button_to should be TURBO_STREAM by default.

Turbo should be enabled by default, however you can changed it manually with:
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = true

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#disabling-turbo-drive-on-specific-links-or-forms
